# Multitenancy and AWS Amplify, AppSync, Cognito

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have been working on the great AWS amplify, Appsync [workshop](https://github.com/rakannimer/amplify-react-workshop/) and I had a couple of questions wrt to these technologies to create a Multitenant application.

A. When a user registers in a multitenant application he would be asked the register the domain that he is trying to register for(this should not have been taken by anyone). I am unable to understand how I would modify the application to request for domain when a user is registering. Is this something that is supported out of the box in Amplify, Cognito? My understanding is ensuring uniqueness of a domain is possible using "pipeline resolvers" in AWS AppSync.

B. When the user registers, the plan was to register him with "his selected domain", "admin role" AWS cognito custom attributes. Is this something that is supported out of the box in Amplify, Cognito? How would I take care of this requirement?

Comment: Could you be more specific `I am unable to understand how I would modify the application to request for domain when a user is registering.` is very high level to understand your problem and very business related.

Comment: Thank you @Neilll, i was looking for help for customizing the signin screen, for multi tenant applications. Based on the signup configuration documentation(https://haverchuck.github.io/docs/js/ionic#signup-configuration), this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but nothing has really changed in the last 3 years...

Made the mistake of believing that the AWS Cognito has viable multi-tenancy support, it does not despite the claims in their documentation, support for it is very weak, the concept in AWS is bad & highly inconvenient, we ended up wasting a months dev time pulling AWS Congnito out, also was not happy with the incomplete state of Amplify or the overall quality.

My team ended up pulling out Cognito after discovering its usage case for multi-tenancy was useless and the user pools concept is awful.
If you need to add more custom fields later, good luck, when you read how you have to do it, you will be far from pleased.

**Custom credentials are not searchable**, for example, you won't be able to query the IDP for a list of users where `custom:domain` has a value of `admin`.

> **Note**
>
> You can only search for standard attributes. Custom attributes are not searchable. This is because only indexed attributes are searchable, and custom attributes cannot be indexed.

The source of this drawback is written here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html

---

Auth0's higher volume tier quotas are eye wateringly expensive.

---

Googles Identity Platform https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform looked far more promising and price fairer.

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants#listing_users

---

In the end though, we decided to write our own IDP service and it has paid off very well for us.